# Flagged as not an answer - Rejected

Tags: support, declined-flags

A while ago I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13235559/why-does-the-java-compiler-not-understand-this-variable-is-always-initialized/13282994#13282994) as "not an answer". However, my flag got the status:

**declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it**

Which I find a bit interesting. I think that the answer should be a comment to Deep's answer **considering he is the only one** who mentions a `getV` method.

Why was this flag declined? Is it just me who thinks it should be a comment to Deep's answer? Am I missing something here?

Comment: On the other hand, at first glance it looks like a honest, if poor quality, attempt to answer.

Comment: @juergend: No, the linked answer really doesn't attempt to answer the question, but to reply to a different answer. It only looks like a valid answer, the flag on itself is valid.

Comment: Whoops. Thanks for shining a brighter light on this answer. It's been flagged four times in the past, and those have been declined or disputed every time.

Comment: @BilltheLizard No problem. I guess even moderators are human. :) Next time will probably use the tip from Madara's answer if such a situation occur again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your flag was declined because **moderators are not experts in all languages**. At first glance, this does indeed look like an answer to the question (albeit a poor one), only someone skilled in the language given would know to tell instantly.

A moderator has reviewed your flag, and decided that it was an answer, so he declined your flag.

### What to do?

Flag it again, this time, use a **custom flag**, explain exactly how it does not answer the question, and what it replies to.

- Custom flags get more attention (as in, time per flag). They cause moderators look closer (though don't use it for everything!!!)
- Custom flags help mods get the bigger picture, and take the best action possible.

Comment: Apparently me asking the question here has brought enough attention to the answer so that it has now been removed. :) Your answer will be good to keep in mind for the future.

Comment: Yup; what Madara said here, @SimonAndréForsberg. I'm one of the two mods who declined a Not an Answer flag on that answer. To me, it seemed like an *attempt* to answer the question. Reading what I have here, I definitely agree with minitech's deletion