# Effect of a user asking the exact same off-topic question on multiple sites

Tags: discussion, support, off-topic, cross-posting

I came across [this question on Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/38690/how-to-create-subdomain-using-php). Then I noticed that the same user had been posting the same thing on four different SE sites. Including [a recent question here on MSO/MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215107/how-to-create-subdomain-using-php).

Now I was wondering: What will be the "punishment" (such a horrible word but I can't find any better one at the moment) for this user? Will there be any immediate automatic thing by the system, or will SE moderators do something manually? I am aware that there is automatic question bans that can trigger on individual sites, but how far should it go before it's a "global" more severe action against this behavior?

Should instances of such mass-posting of questions on different SE sites be flagged for moderator attention, and if so, what would be a good custom-message to flag with? (I've been told before that when using a custom flag, it is good to [also include a suggested action](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203458/a-declined-flag-with-a-custom-reason) that should be taken by the moderator)

Comment: Flag it as 'other' and explain what you've noticed. The mod will visit the mod chat room to discuss with the mods on those other sites as well. Also, it's likely that the OT post would have been spotted on other SE sites too and deleted, so you wouldn't see that on their post history. The mods will hand it over to one of the main Stack Exchange comms team to deal with. Individual site mods can only deal with issues directly effecting one site, not globally, but they can report and discuss issues directly with other mods and SE staff comms team.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cross posting is generally frowned upon, and it is probably best to leave it up to the mods so they can coordinate it between them with the moderators from the other site(s). In instances where a user posts the same questions to multiple sites, these questions should be flagged for moderator attention.

For the custom flag text, just include the fact it was cross posted with links to the other instances of the question in the custom reason so that the moderator(s) that deal with it can get to them quickly without having to search for the duplicates.